# How can I use user fields in panels title

Tags: 7, panels

This seems to be basic but I cannot get my head around it and I am rather stuck. I am trying to have a panel override in D7 on the user profile page and access a few fields that I have defined in a user profile type (first name and surname in profile2)

I have added a context of the profile type in the panel and set the title to use the content pane title. I add the profile field, how can I set this field to be the panel title?

Any help welcome please.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the gear icon on the grey bar for your field you have added, and click set as panel title.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've been looking at this problem all day and I realised that the issue is larger than not showing up in title. Page manager and Profile2 don't play well together. Others that encounter same behaviour might find useful this thread http://drupal.org/node/1273026